# Can i covert this in a CSV format where all the element gonna be under one row, without repeating the doc attribute?

Tags: json, csv

[
{
"doc": "ghgagsa",
"element": [
{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Doe"
},
{
"firstName": "Anna",
"lastName": "Smith"
},
{
"firstName": "Peter",
"lastName": "Jones"
}
]
},
{
"doc": "ghgagsaaa",
"element": [
{
"firstName": "Joaahn",
"lastName": "Doae"
},
{
"firstName": "Anana",
"lastName": "Smiath"
},
{
"firstName": "Petaaer",
"lastName": "Jonaes"
}
]
}
]

Comment: Suggest you format the JSON using editor. And please post the desired output for your sample data - also formatted using editor.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), it's `.[].element[]|[.firstName,.lastName]|@csv`

Here an example https://jqplay.org/s/XmlRS6Yh9v